# Software for Mac OS X to view movies on my PS3 or Xbox 360

Tags: software-recommendation, sharing

I want to see movies that are on my Mac on the screen connected to my PS3 or Xbox 360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PS3mediaserver](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/)

Supposedly works with XBox 360 as well.  Supports streaming and transcoding.

Answer (score 3):

Nullriver Software:

[Medialink - PS3](http://www.nullriver.com/products/medialink)

[Connect360 - Xbox360](http://www.nullriver.com/products/connect360)

Comment: I have used Connect360 for the last few years. Very solid and works nice, but I would recommend Rivet above it I think.

Answer (score 1):

I use [MediaLink](http://www.nullriver.com/products/medialink), which lets you use your Mac as a server which the PS3 can connect to for music, pictures, and movies.  It seems to work well enough; my only problem is that I don't like the PS3's interface for browsing through large collections of things.  For example, when sharing my entire iTunes library, I'm just about restricted to playlists or random shuffle -- pulling a particular artist/album/song out of thousands is just a pain.  For movies, it's worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Rivet](http://thelittleappfactory.com/rivet/) for streaming to my PS3. It's completely painless to set up, while I've had trouble with another solution in the past (unfortunately I can't remember the name of that one).

Comment: Works for the Xbox 360 as well!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vuze for that: http://www.vuze.com/features/device
Not sure if there are any alternatives for OSX.